# Path for logs is not writable

Tags: codeception

When I'm running codecept run on the first try after bootstrap, I'm running into this error,

[Codeception\Exception\Configuration]
Path for logs is not writable. Please, set appropriate access mode for log path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but `chmod 777 _log` resulted in `no such file or directory`.

Use: `chmod 777 -R tests/_log`

Answer (score 1):

For me, _log file was already there but I was still getting the same error.

My problem was solved when I used SUDO with my execution command.

Answer (score 0):

I created _log folder inside the folder, "/tests" and gave it a write access,

```
chmod 777 _log
```